# Django, Pinax, couldn't extract file

Tags: python, django, pinax, pythonanywhere

I'm following the exact directions of getting started with pinax-project-account. You can see them [here][1]. I just created my virtual environment and installed the requirements. The problem with when I run this command: `django-admin.py startproject --template=https://github.com/pinax/pinax-project-account/zipball/master`.  I get this error:

CommandError: couldn't extract file /tmp/django_project_template_e1ulrY_downl
oad/master.html to /tmp/django_project_template_wU3ju6_extract: Path not a re
cognized archive format: /tmp/django_project_template_e1ulrY_download/master.
html

I can get this working on my local machine but I'm using python anywhere and it doesn't seem to like this command? 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The `.html` at the end of `/tmp/django_project_template_e1ulrY_download/master.html` seems suspect to me. I'm guessing that you got an error html page instead of the archive you requested. Check the contents of that file to see what happened.

Comment: Update from a PythonAnywhere dev: this question was also asked on our forums, and we worked out what the problem was.  Details here: https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/2718/#id_post_15582